# Show Bootstrap login modal over Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a webpage that will load Google Maps API as a background, and then check if the user is logged in. If they are logged in, the page will load data from the database and update the map (haven't programmed that much, just a placeholder alert). If the user is not logged in, then a Bootstrap modal should show up with a login form. However, I'm having troubles getting the modal to show up on the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Smart Force Tracker</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.40, -97.5),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exhours) {
       var d = new Date();
       d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exhours*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
       document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
       var name = cname + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
           var c = ca[i];
           while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
           if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
               return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
           }
       }
       return "";
    }

    function checkLogin() {

       initialize();

       var isLogin=getCookie("isLogin");
       if (isLogin != "") {
           alert("Welcome again " + isLogin);
       } else {
          $("#loginModal").modal("show");
       }
    }
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body onload="checkLogin()">

    <div class="container">
       <div id="map-canvas">

       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="model-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-signin">
                   <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
                   <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus>
                   <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                   <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Register</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
#map-canvas 
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: setting #map-canvas to -1 will cause it to be below the viewable layer.  try setting it to z-index:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look inside the console might be helpful:

**Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

you must load jquery-2.1.3.min.js **before** bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code a bit..  I changed the z-index on your #map-canvas.  I also rearanged your javascript.

The modal now shows up over the map.

This is what you wanted correct?  Let me know in the comments if it isn't.

***Javascript:***

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.40, -97.5),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    checkLogin();
  }

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exhours) {
   var d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exhours*60*60*1000));
   var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
   document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
       if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
           return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
       }
   }
   return "";
}

function checkLogin() {

   var isLogin=getCookie("isLogin");
   if (isLogin != "") {
       alert("Welcome again " + isLogin);
   } else {
      $("#loginModal").modal("show");
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();    
});
```

***CSS:***

```
#map-canvas 
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index:0;
}
```

***Working Fiddle:***
http://jsfiddle.net/cwytqLfm/

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.

I can tell from the Fiddle that it's supposed to work, but I can't seem to get it to work when loaded locally on my own machine or when uploaded to my website, even when I copy everything over.

Guess I'll have to keep messing with it.

Comment: Maybe I can help you with this.. do you have the url of the site?